# SQL Injection Training challenge including a PHP file

Tags: php, sql-injection

I’m currently trying to get some knowledge in SQL injection. In a pen test environment, there is a challenge on which you get the PHP file and you need to try to login using SQL Injection. I’ve already tried several injections but cannot find a way in.

My PHP knowledge is quite basic. May someone help me and give me a hint?

I’ve already tried to create a new user for example using the following injection:

```
sdf'OR '1'='1'; INSERT INTO login (id,username,password,password_hash) VALUES (40,'test','test','16ac651ed2af60604b7055513c30c459')--

sdf'OR '1'='1'; INSERT INTO login (id,username,password,password_hash) VALUES (40,'test','test','d539c02f61ff111c79d42e6448cb1f45')--

sdf'OR '1'='1' UNION ALL INSERT INTO login (id,username,password,password_hash) VALUES (40,'test','test','16ac651ed2af60604b7055513c30c459') --
```

Here is the provided PHP file:

```
###############################################################################################

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
/*====================================SQL====================================*/

$random = "*****************";

$_error_  = "";

if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];
                $hash    = "none";
               
                $query  = "SELECT id, username, password, password_hash FROM login WHERE username = '" . $username . "'";
              

                $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
               
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                $userarray = $result->fetch_assoc();
                }
               
                $hash = md5($random . $username . $password);
                if ($hash == $userarray["password_hash"]) {
                                session_start();
                                $_SESSION['simple_login'] = $username;
                                header("Location: home.php");
                                exit();
                } else {
                                $_error_ = "Invalid Login";
                                echo $_error_;
                }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
###############################################################################################
```

Comment: You show what you have tried, but what's the result? Is there output? Errors? Anything?

Comment: The database might be read only in such challenges. Perhaps consider a different approach.

Comment: looks on the same line as https://www.shysecurity.com/post/20140705-SQLi-Quine